# Angular - find out if derived class implements an abstract class (router.component)

Tags: angular, typescript, abstract-class

I'm trying to use `router.component` to set page title. So, I created an abstract class which has to provide title:

```
export abstract class ComponentWithTitleBase {
  abstract get title(): Observable<string>;
}
```

and then the component that implements it looks like this:

```
export class AboutComponent extends ComponentWithTitleBase implements OnInit {
  get title(): Observable<string> {
    return of("About the demo");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Now I just need to use it with router events. I subscribe and see if `router.component` is `ComponentWithTitleBase`, so:

```
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        // identify navigation end
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        // now query the activated route
        map(() => this.rootRoute(this.route)),
        filter((route) => !!route.component),
        tap((route: ActivatedRoute) =>
          console.log(route.component instanceof ComponentWithTitleBase)
        ),
...
```

But whatever I do the output is `false`. Is there any way I could find out if some class implements another ***abstract*** class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instanceof`  does not work for an abstract class,

Replace `route.component instanceof ComponentWithTitleBase` with
`ComponentWithTitleBase.isPrototypeOf(route.component)`